# What is the symbolic link "ubuntu-default-greyscale-wallpaper" used for?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

When I do this:

```
ll /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

I see this link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx ... ubuntu-default-greyscale-wallpaper.png -> Beaver_Wallpaper_Grey_4096x2304.png
```

Why is this link to a Default Grey Wallpaper there?

I have some ideas: Perhaps it is used during Hibernation or Suspend, or when a Ubuntu runs as a Virtual machine and is "Paused" .

Anyone?